# Environment detection functions not working

Tags: php, testing, var

I face a strange problem with this simple test which refuses to work.

I need to detect on which environment I am (local, Inte, Preprod or Prod).

I wrote the following codes but none are working.

```php
function getTypeOfServer2() {

    $env_server = 'Unknown';

    if($_ENV['SERVER_NAME']==='subdomain.local.host.mydomain.fr') {
        $env_server = 'Dev';
    }
    elseif ($_ENV['SERVER_NAME']==='subdomain.inte.mydomain.fr') {
        $env_server = 'Inte';
    }
    elseif ($_ENV['SERVER_NAME']==='subdomain.preprod.mydomain.fr') {
        $env_server = 'Preprod';
    }
    elseif($_ENV['SERVER_NAME']==='subdomain.mydomain.fr') {
        $env_server = '';
    }

    return $env_server;
}



function getTypeOfServer3() {

    switch ($_ENV['SERVER_NAME']) {
        case 'subdomain.local.host.mydomain.fr':
            $env_server = 'Dev';
            break;
        case 'subdomain.inte.mydomain.fr':
            $env_server = 'Inte';
            break;
        case 'subdomain.preprod.mydomain.fr':
            $env_server = 'Preprod';
            break;
        case 'subdomain.mydomain.fr':
            $env_server = '';
            break;
        default:
           $env_server = 'Unknown';
    }

    return $env_server;
}
```

On Inte environment, if I do a simple
`echo "global var : ".$_ENV['SERVER_NAME']."<br>";`
it returns subdomain.inte.mydomain.fr
But both functions returns anyhow 'Dev'

Comment: Perhaps you intended to write `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead of `$_ENV['SERVER_NAME']`? Apart from that, why use these strange abbreviations? "local, Inte, Preprod or Prod", I can guess what most of them mean but "Inte" stumped me. I'm an advocate for using the keyboard that you have: "development" not "dev", "integration" not "inte", and so on. The reason is simple: If someone else reads your code they might actually understand it. Using unnecessary abbreviations is indefensible.

Comment: Thanks KIKO Software for your help. Unfortunatly $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and $_ENV['SERVER_NAME'] print the same thing. My main concern is that I can print out the variable but why does the test fail when I compare the variable value with its value ? (problem is not retreiving the variable, but making the test succeed)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why it won't work. I can't test your code. It looks alright, apart from the abbreviations that is. 

Comment: If something works in one place but not another, you might want to start running `var_dump` on things. Also, `$_ENV` is writable by anyone, so is it possible that something is changing it?

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware and Chris-hass for your help. The CI/CD is dockerized and quite complexe ; this is why I stick with the abreviations used everywhere in the project. I also suspect a difference in Dev (local) environment and deployment (Inte, Preprod and Prod) environments. This is not php version (already checked). The strange thing is that if I run any of the 2 tests (if or switch above versions) in a page of the CMS ; they both return the right environment ; but if I call the functions getTypeOfServer2() or getTypeOfServer3() contained in a utils.inc page ; then they fail...

Comment: I'm still leaning towards something modifying your environment variables. Maybe try coping the array very early, `$MY_ENV = $_ENV;` and using that global in your function to prove that one way or another. You could also grep for `putenv` calls.

Comment: thanks @ChrisHaas for follow-up. I just found the below solution ; which passed all tests on different environments. 

  function getTypeOfServer() {

    $url = explode(".", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

    switch ($url[1]) {
        case 'local':
            $env_server = 'Dev';
            break;
        case 'inte':
            $env_server = 'Inte';
            break;
etc...


Not the nicest think I did, but i works.

I suspect the problem comes from the points in the url which are maybe considered as concatenation ??? If someone knows, I will be happy to ear about you

Answer (score -1):

```php
function getTypeOfServer() {

     $url = explode(".", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

     switch ($url[1])
        case 'local':
            $env_server = 'Dev';
            break;
        case 'inte':
            $env_server = 'Inte';
            break;
        case 'preprod':
            $env_server = 'Preprod';
            break;
        case 'mydomain':
            $env_server = '';
            break;
        default:
           $env_server = 'Unknown';
    }

    return $env_server;
}
```

Quite close from my initial code ; but the points in the url seem to be the problem.